# Laravel 5 How to show throttle message like session flash?

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 5.4, and i want to limit request of the route like below

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['throttle:2']], function () {

    Route::post('/xxx', 'TestController@getTest');

});
```

It works well but when received "Too Many Attempts." it shows on a blank page. Is there way to display this like session flash messages in a blade view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, an easy way to do this is to change your throttle middleware.

First, create a new middleware which extends the base throttle middleware like this :

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests as 
BaseThrottleRequests;

class ThrottleRequests extends BaseThrottleRequests
{
}
```

And then change your throttle middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php:

```
'throttle' => \App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class
```

It will now use your own throttle middleware and as it extends from the one from laravel, it has its functionalities and works like before.

Then, looking inside the base class, you will find that `buildResponse` builds the response in case of a Too Many Attemps case. Therefore, you just need to override it inside your middleware :

```
protected function buildResponse($key, $maxAttempts)
{
    $retryAfter = $this->limiter->availableIn($key); // This gives you the number of seconds before the next time it is available

    return redirect('test')->with('error', '...'); // You can use redirect() and all those stuffs as you would normally do to redirect the user and set a session message
}
```

Comment: Alex i have one more question. Your solution works great but i display error message hard coded like this :  `return redirect('test')->with('error', 'Try 10 minutes later');`    is it possible to display Retry-After time dynamic ?  i mean if 5 minute left display 'Try 5 minutes later' etc..

Comment: Well that's just string concatenation, just calculate the minutes and the seconds and display them, `$seconds = $retryAfter % 60`, `$minutes = ($retryAfter - $seconds) / 60` and then you can make your message

Answer (score 2):

Create a middleware e.g. CustomThrottleRequests
extend ThrottleRequests middleware in it

Override handle method

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 60, $decayMinutes = 1, $prefix = '')
{
    $key = $prefix.$this->resolveRequestSignature($request);

    $maxAttempts = $this->resolveMaxAttempts($request, $maxAttempts);

    if ($this->limiter->tooManyAttempts($key, $maxAttempts)) {
        $retryAfter = $this->getTimeUntilNextRetry($key);
         $retryAfter is in seconds
         //here you can change response according to requirements
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error','Too Many Attempts. Please try after '.$retryAfter .' seconds');
    }

    $this->limiter->hit($key, $decayMinutes * 60);

    $response = $next($request);

    return $this->addHeaders(
        $response, $maxAttempts,
        $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts)
    );
}
```

Now in  app/Http/Kernel.php

```
  change from 
  'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
   to
 'throttle' => CustomThrottleRequests::class,
```